# How to differentiate viewing access to certain apis in swagger ui view java?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

When sending a request to localhost/swagger-ui/index.html I get all the documentation of my application. Is it possible to make sure that only certain APIs are visible to certain users or users with certain roles?
In my application, I use SecurityContextHolder for access control, from which I can get data about the user: his role, privileges, etc.

I tried using the @PreAuthorize annotation on the counter-controllers, but I still see the API in the documentation.

My swagger configuration:

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:OpenAPIConfig.yaml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
@Configuration
public class OpenAPIConfig {

   @Bean
   @Primary
   public SpringDocConfiguration springDocConfiguration() {
       return new SpringDocConfiguration();
   }

   @Bean
   public SpringDocConfigProperties springDocConfigProperties() {
       return new SpringDocConfigProperties();
   }

   @Bean
   public ObjectMapperProvider objectMapperProvider(SpringDocConfigProperties    springDocConfigProperties) {
       return new ObjectMapperProvider(springDocConfigProperties);
   }

   @Bean
   public SpringDocUIConfiguration springDocUIConfiguration(Optional<SwaggerUiConfigProperties> optionalSwaggerUiConfigProperties) {
       return new SpringDocUIConfiguration(optionalSwaggerUiConfigProperties);
   }
}
```

OpenAPIConfig.yaml:

```
springdoc:
 api-docs:
  enabled: false
 swagger-ui:
  urls:
  - url: "/ApiDocumentation1.yaml"
    name: "Doc1"
  - url: "/ApiDocumentation2.yaml"
    name: "Doc2"
```